# AngularJS service proper way how to write functions conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I have loginForm service, which takes care of my login form behaviour. For example there is default function for what to do when the login was successful, but let's say that In deferent places I want the login form to behave differently.

I wrote it like this, but it's not the proper way I think. Should I write it differently use for example Angulars (extend) function?

```
angular.module('flapperNews').factory('loginForm', ['Auth', function(Auth) {

    function defaultSuccess() {
        alert('succes');
    }

    function defaultFail() {
        alert('fail');
    }

    var service = {
        fields: function() {
            return fields;
        },
        submitForm: function(loginInfo, afterSuccess, afterFail) {

            // Test if login ifnormation are right
            Auth.login(loginInfo).then(function(user) {

                // If new after success function is provided use it, if not use default
                (afterSuccess > 0) ? afterSuccess() : defaultSuccess();
            }, function(errorData) {
                // If new after success function is provided use it, if not use default
                (afterSuccess > 0) ? afterFail() : defaultFail();
            });
        },
    };

    return service;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can come up with 3 possible solutions that would all make sense in a cetain scenario:

- Callbacks (what you have done)
- Broadcast events on $rootScope and let the controllers handle themselves
- Pass in a argument that decideds what part of logic is supposed to be used / run and put the logic into the service.

In an login scenario id broadcast a event and let controllers handle the event.

Comment: would be it possible for you to show me some code examples? I would greatly appreciate it.